# Passing urls and IDs back and forth using flask jinja2 and bootstrap templates

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

Flask/jinja2/bootstrap noob here. I'm using flask, jinja2 and bootstrap templates to make a basic webpage. Using the {% for product in products %} below, I'm trying to display multiple panels of products (in this case from Amazon), and I'm trying to use the {{product['imgurl']}} to assign an image url within each panel. Apart from this, as there are multiple buttons being created using the {% for product in products %}, I would also like to detect which button has been clicked and somehow pass this back to the next page that is called when the button is clicked, both questions are detailed below:

```
   <div class="container">
    <div class="starter-template">
     <h1><span class="label label-primary">Here are the top results:</span></h1>

     {% for product in products %}
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="{{product['imgurl']}}" alt="...">
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>{{product['name']}}</h3>
            <p>{{product['blurb']}}</p>
            <p><a href="/output2" class="btn btn-primary" role="button"><element id={{ product['ASIN']}}>Choose Set</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
     </div>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
     <script src="static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </div> <!-- /.container-->
```

1. I want my html code to use the product['imgurl'] variable to source the image from an external website, I know how to do this for a single 'img src=', but not how to do it in a for loop.
2. The second question is getting the ID of the button that was clicked. As you can see from code above, I'm using "element id={{ product['ASIN']}}" to assign an ID to each button, but how do I integrate the 'id' of the button being clicked into the resulting "a href=""" call, so the 'id is passed along to the next page?

I'm not sure if this can be done within the flask/jinja2/bootstrap framework. If it can, any help/solution on this would be much appreciated, I have spent a lot of time searching for this so far, but I've been unable to find an clear answer or approach. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question 1, I think you can use the dot notation instead of indexing dictionaries.

```
{% for product in products %}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="{{product.imgurl}}" alt="...">
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>{{product.name}}</h3>
            <p>{{product.blurb}}</p>
            <p>
                <a href="/output2" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">
                    <element id={{ product.ASIN}}>Choose Set</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

For the second question and to get the id of an element, I like to do the following:

```
{% for product in products %}
      <div class="row">
          <a class="itemId" data-item-id="{{product.id}}">Click here to get the id</a>
      </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Then you can use jQuery and do this:

```
$(".itemId").click(function(){
    var itemId = $(this).data("item-id");
    alert(itemId);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the first suggestion, that really helped, I don't think I explained the 2nd correctly, I want users to have a button for each image, to pick between the images displayed. What I really want to do is capture which button was clicked, from the multiple buttons displayed and pass that to the resulting href="" call, so the next page that's called by the click

Comment: @bnnrs as I see in your code you only have one image per product, so you can follow my approach to track image clicks and then do something accordingly, let me know if/why it does not work for you...

Answer (score 1):

```
 <p><a href="/output2?{{product.ASIN}}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Choose Set</a></p>
```

This did the trick, it took the product.ASIN that was associated with the current frame and passed it onto the next page!!